# How add tooltip in flexdashboard navbar icon?

Tags: html, css, r

I have this [application](https://giovani.shinyapps.io/0_example/) in `R`.

How add tooltip when I hover over the icon? Like this:

[image]

The icon class is `.fa-question-circle`. I tried:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class=".fa-question-circle" data-tooltip="My text is a text">Text</a>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-question-circle 
{
    position:relative;
}

.fa-question-circle:after
{
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    color: white;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    display:none;
    padding:5px;
    position:absolute;
    right: -105px;
    bottom: -55px;
    z-index:3;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.fa-question-circle:hover:after {
    display:block;
}
```

But doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the wrong part. you need use `class="fa-question-circle"` not `class=".fa-question-circle"`

```css
.fa-question-circle 
{
    position:relative;
}

.fa-question-circle:after
{
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    color: white;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    display:none;
    padding:5px;
    position:absolute;
    right: -105px;
    bottom: -55px;
    z-index:3;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.fa-question-circle:hover:after {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="fa-question-circle" data-tooltip="My text is a text">Text</a>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. :(. See my application and see HTML with `Ctrl + Shift + C` to see if you understand better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this and remove `.` from the class name in your `anchor` tag.

```css
.fa-question-circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.fa-question-circle .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fa-question-circle:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="fa-question-circle">Text
 <span class="tooltiptext">My text is a text</span>
</a>
```